# One Xcode iOS Template inside another

Tags: ios, xcode

Does choosing any template while creating Xcode (Single View Application, Master Detail Application, Page Based Application, Tabbed Application) project means I can not change the application UI later?

Can I have Master Detail View + Page Based view inside a Single view Application? 
Im new to iOS So please bear with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make whatever changes you want. The original template you choose simply gives you an initial app with a storyboard setup with the minimum needed. The single view just gives you a single view controller. The master detail gives you a split view controller setup with a master view controller and a table view in a navigation controller for the detail view controller.

With that starting point you can add, edit, or completely replace that setup to meet your needs.

Comment: Can I have a 2 master detail view controller inside a single view controller?

Comment: You can create just about any UI you want but you won’t get such a setup initially from any of the templates.